# Counting table rows in PHP

Tags: php, sql, php-5.1

I am working on a project and I need to find a way to count the table rows when a user has selected a Group from the drop-down box. I have tried some ways in which I can show, but also I am not grasping how this concept would work. I am also using an SQL database which works perfectly, the rows is giving me a hard time though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="Web4.php" method="post">
    <label form="return">Group: </label>
    <select id="return" name="return">
        <option value="G">All</option>
        <option value="A">Group A</option>
        <option value="B">Group B</option>
        <option value="C">Group C</option>
        <option value="D">Group D</option>
        <option value="E">Group E</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydatabasename";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
}

if(!isset($_POST["return"])) {$selval ="G";}
else {$selval = $_POST["return"];}

if($selval == "G"){
   $scores = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from test_scores;");
}
elseif($selval == "A"){
    $scores = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from test_scores WHERE group_id='A';");
}
elseif($selval == "B"){
   $scores = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from test_scores WHERE group_id='B';");
}
elseif($selval == "C"){
  $scores = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from test_scores WHERE group_id='C';");
}
elseif($selval == "D"){
  $scores = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from test_scores WHERE group_id='D';");
}
else{
   $scores = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from test_scores WHERE group_id='E';");
}


?>


<table border="1">
<tr><th>Record ID</th><th>Math Score</th><th>Reading Score</th><th>Writing Score</th></td></tr>

<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($scores)){
   echo "<tr><td>".$row["group_id"]."</td><td>".$row["math"]."</td><td>".$row["reading"]."</td><td>".$row["writing"]."</td></tr>\n";
}

?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you used `count(*)` in the SQL? You could use `$selval` as a parameter in your query then only need 1 SQL statement. If you are using 5.1 version of PHP you should reallly consider upgrading or having your host upgrade you.

Comment: I have not, how would you implement that? @user3783243

Comment: Instead of the `*` use `count(*)` or use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php if you need the data of every row as well... or if you are asking about using the variable see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php Query would become `select * from test_scores WHERE group_id=?`

Comment: Do not ever write database access code inside your file with HTML template. At least move it into the second file and function in it and use include / require